# Insert data to sqlite android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-layout

I have following query to insert values in sqlite table,

```
Insert Into T (Test) Values (' 42'SIZE ')
```

But it give me an error for inserting such data.

This is valid SQL syntax.

I am just in problem with 42 **Inches** = ' 42'LED TV Size ' should be inserting into the db.

Comment: Your SQL isn't valid, so it makes sense that you would get an error.

Comment: Could You please show Your code?

Comment: You're indicating that you are entering a single column (the Test column) into your table, but your value has a string `'42'` followed by some stray text.

Comment: 42' LED TV Like that its string so its 42 inches did you get my point?

Comment: Getting your point is not so relevant; you providing valid SQL strings is :)   But yes, I understand now; I'll provide a good answer for you below.

Comment: Do you want insert SIZE as a astring or it will have some value, like **42'34** or **42'SIZE**.?

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
INSERT INTO T (Test) VALUES ('42', SIZE)
```

(assuming 'T' is your table).

Comment: That's exactly what he has in his question, isn't it?

Comment: Ah sorry, I missed that :)

Comment: I want to insert 42'LED TV Size in db but its give me an error

Comment: Ah ok you want to skip the quote right?

Comment: yes exactly also I can not remove from string

Answer (score 1):

Invalid sql...

```
INSERT INTO table_name
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)
```

Or if you only want specific parts of the table filled:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to insert the value `42' SIZE` and since this is a string, you're enclosing it within quotes... the problem you're facing is there is a quote within it which is disrupting your string and SQL doesn't know how to reconcile it. You must "escape" the quote that will be part of your string (so that it is not part of the full SQL statement).

The SQLite method is to simply place a second quote, which would give you:
`Insert Into T (Test) Values (' 42''SIZE ')`.

The standard method is to use a backslash however I don't think SQLite allows that. I tried it just to check, using the sqlite3 command line tool, and it wasn't happy with my using backslash as an escape method.

Comment: Yeah I also thought backslashes would work, but they don't :/